# Signalr Xamarin Client Unhandled Error on HubConnection.Start()

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, signalr

I have followed along with a signalr sample and got a webpage running signlar on a server. I am now trying to connect an Android(Xamarin) client to this same server but am getting an Unhandled Exception when calling connection.Start().

This is my signalr Hub which i know works because the webpage calls it successfully.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace WebApplication.Hubs
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void SendNow(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.displayMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

My Android Class that's trying to connect to this Hub but fails.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Widget;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

class SignalClient
{
    private HubConnection _connection;
    private IHubProxy _proxy;
    private TextView BoxView;
    private string _user;

    public SignalClient(string user, TextView outputBox)
    {
        BoxView = outputBox;
        _user = user;
    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        _connection = new HubConnection("http://websiteurl/chatapp/");
        _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");


        _proxy.On("displayMessage", (string user, string message) =>
        {
            SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
            {
                BoxView.Text += ("{0}: {1}\n", user, message);
            }, null);
        });

        await _connection.Start(); //<- Unhandled Exception
        await Send("Connected");
    }

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return _proxy.Invoke("SendNow", _user, message);
    }
}
```

I've tried all variation of the url i can think of. from the base website url, adding the subdomain I've published to, and both variations with signalr/ at the end.

Been stuck here a few days... Any help or direction to look in would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit 1: Here is call stack

```
    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal  C#
0x1 in System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException  C#
0x20 in object.7424197e-7e83-40fd-ba05-2908dff2d689 C#
0x12 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#
0x6 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0    C#
0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. C#
0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run C#
0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run C#
0x11 in object.7424197e-7e83-40fd-ba05-2908dff2d689 C#
```

Comment: Paste the stack trace of the exception in your question. If you don´t get a stack trace, wrap the `await _connection.Start()` call in a try-catch

Comment: @xleon Well this is what confuses me. I'm unable to get any more info than the error happened in [External Code]. I assume this means the error happened within Signalr because the url was wrong. Is there any way to get more info on what went happened?

Comment: Is your server running on IIS express or a remote server?

Comment: Are you sure you can´t catch the exception with a try-catch?

Comment: About the lack of info in the exception. Try disabling "Just My Code": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @xleon Running on remote IIS server, also thanks got call stack info

Comment: what version of Signalr Client are you using?

Comment: @xleon Signalr Client version 2.2.2. Server was running signalr 2.1.2, I upgraded it to 2.2.2, No Success. I tried downgrading the Signalr client to 2.1.2 but it wont install.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the URL you pass to `HubConnection` is the URL of the hub.

You're passing `"http://websiteurl/chatapp/"` - are you sure this is the hub's URL and not the web site's URL?

Comment: No I am not certain I'm using the Hub URL, I've tried all of these variations though
"http://websiteurl/chatapp/signalr"
"http://websiteurl/signalr"
"http://websiteurl/chatapp/signalr/hubs"
"http://websiteurl/signalr/hubs"
"http://websiteurl/"
I'm confused though because this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) says putting in the base URL should work